# Errors during compiling simple program in CLion

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation, clion

I have a problems compiling simple "Hello World" program in CLion on Linux Solus. Might be because of wrong compiler settings, or something like that, but I ran out of ideas, so I'll be happy if any of you have a solution.
I have gcc, gdb and cmake installed, so I don't think anything is missing...

I get this errors when trying to run example program:

[image: CLion compiling]

I'll be grateful for any help, because I instaled it on Fedora, Mint and Windows and it works without problems... I have only trouble with Solus.

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem is that your dev environment hasn't been fully setup yet. Run the command:

```
sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```